# Instances of abstract class cannot be created unless i write to database first

Tags: c#, mongodb, instance, abstract-class

I have two functions one for write and one for read when i try to use the read function first i get this error:

> An error occurred while deserializing the Message property of class DDSRecorder.MessageContainer: Instances of abstract classes cannot be created

Here is what i dont get, if i use the write first at least once then the read works fine. i dont understand what happens in the background that makes it ok to initialize abstract class if we used it once to write.

Adding the map for it didn't resolve the problem:

```
if (BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(MessageContainer)))
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MessageBase>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
    });
}
```

Here is the class i am using for the mongo collection.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
public class MessageContainer
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string MessageType { get; set; }

    public MessageBase Message { get; set; }

    [BsonConstructor]
    public MessageContainer()
    {

    }

    [BsonConstructor]
    public MessageContainer(MessageBase message)
    {
        Message = message ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));
        TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        MessageType = message.GetType().Name;
    }

    [BsonConstructor]
    public MessageContainer(DateTime timeStamp, string messageType, MessageBase message)
    {
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        MessageType = messageType ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(messageType));
        Message = message ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));
    }  
}
```

And the abstract class inside:

```
public abstract class MessageBase
    {
        protected MessageBase();

        public MessageBase CreateCopy();
    }
```

Example of write method:

```
public bool Write(MessageContainer message)
{
    if (message != null && _mongoCollection != null)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(MessageContainer)))
            {
                BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MessageContainer>();
                BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MessageBase>(cm =>
                {
                    cm.AutoMap();
                    cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
                });
            }

            _mongoCollection.InsertOne(message);
           
            return true;                                      
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Example of read method:

```
public bool GetFirstAndLastMessageTime(out DateTime firstMessageTime, out DateTime lastMessageTime)
{
  if (BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(MessageContainer)))
  {
      BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MessageBase>(cm =>
      {
          cm.AutoMap();
          cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
      });
  }
  
  var filter = Builders<MessageContainer>.Filter.Empty;    
  var first = _mongoCollection.Find(filter).Sort(Builders<MessageContainer>.Sort.Ascending("TimeStamp")).Limit(5).ToList().First();
  var last = _mongoCollection.Find(filter).Sort(Builders<MessageContainer>.Sort.Descending("TimeStamp")).Limit(5).ToList().First();       
  firstMessageTime = first.TimeStamp; 
  lastMessageTime = last.TimeStamp;
  return true;
}
```

What am i missing for it to be able to initialize the abstract class without the need of writing first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, kind of an anti-pattern here (I don't like adding dependencies from base classes to their implementations), but a quick fix would be to add

```cs
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(MyImplementation))]
```

where `MyImplementation` is the type that implements your abstract class.

on your `MessageBase` class. For me this did the trick - I was able to read the data and deserialize just fine. I didn't have to add any class maps either.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided amitla is correct, it was not something that worked for me for multiple reasons.

One is I didn't want to change the abstract class and write down all of the implementations as tags.

Another note is that I found out from the MongoDB forums that apparently the reason for it working only after write is an auto mapper and that is why it worked for me after write.

So to make work this is what I did:

```cs
public void RegisterClassMapping(List<string> messagesType)
{
    // Map base class first
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MessageBase>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
    });

    if (messagesType.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string message in messagesType) // Do look up for each message
        {
            Type type = GetType("NAMEOFTHENAMESPACE." + message);

            if (type == null)
            {
                type = GetType("NAMEOFTHENAMESPACE." + message);
            }

            if (type != null && !BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(type))
            {
                BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the generic GetType I used:

```cs
private Type GetType(string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    if (type != null) return type;

    foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        type = a.GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null)
            return type;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I just run this once and its working for the rest of session.